# How to upgrade Ubuntu 11.04 Server from Ubuntu 11.10 Server CD

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 11.04 Installed and have Ubuntu 11.10 Server CD. If I enter do-release-upgrade in command line Ubuntu starts downloading from Remote Servers. I wan to upgrade from CD. Please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to follow the official upgrade guide, don't you think? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades#Upgrading_Using_the_Alternate_CD.2BAC8-DVD

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the CD and type:

```
gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

Keep in mind that upgrading a system is never a wise idea, especially if it is a production server. More often than not, the upgrade might break something forcing you to reinstall.

The best way would be to make a backup, then erase the hard  disk and perform a clean install.